# Set SetDataSource Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2017 dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll could not found

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I installed VS2017 and run my app(.net 3.5). But I get the error when I call setDataSource of report

This is my code:

```
DataTable data = new RateFactorBO().EstimateActualHour();
                if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string _reportname = "~/Reports/EstimateActualHrsRep.rpt";
                    report.Load(Server.MapPath(_reportname));
                    report.SetDataSource(data);
                }
```

and this is error:

```
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Note: I installed CRforVS_13_0_24 and try to add startup in web.config but it still does not work:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
```

Can someone advice me on what to do?